# how to perform a index search from an array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

im trying to perform an index search for string, it runs but the problem is that it only prints out i[0] which is my first entry. if i lookup another entry it doesn't work. Please help..
    void clist(string fn[],string ln[], int size);

```
int search_list(const string fn[],const string ln[], int size, string find);

int main(){

    string search;

    cout << "This program searches a list .\n";

    const int total = 3;

    string fn[total];
    string ln[total];

    clist(fn,ln, total);

    cout << "Search contact:____  ";

    cin >> search;

    search_list(fn,ln, total, search);

  return 0;

}

void clist(string fn[],string ln[], int size){

    cout << "Enter " << size << " contact.\n";

    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
     cin >> fn[index] >> ln[index] ;

}

int search_list(const string fn[], const string ln[],int size, string search){

   for(int i=0;i<size;i++){

     if((fn[i] == search)&& (i < size)){

       cout<<"Result found "<<fn[i]<<" "<<ln[i]<<endl;

      break;

              }

    cout<<"no record found"<<endl;

     break;

    }

}
```

Comment: Is it a homework? Please tag it as homework in case

Comment: In the future, you don't need to create the same question three times in one day. You can edit your questions if you want to add new or additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a loop and explicitly telling it to `break` out of it after the first iteration. Try writting it like this:

```
bool found = false;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
 if(fn[i] == search){ // No need to check for(i < size)
   found = true;
   cout<<"Result found "<<fn[i]<<" "<<ln[i]<<endl;
   break;
 }
}

if(!found)
  cout<<"no record found"<<endl;
```

Comment: thank you, right in front of me. I have a question off the record. how did you learn c++. i want to learn and i really struggling. any recommendation, tutorials, or advice other than practicing. because practicing alone is not enough when you can find certain errors like this one.

Comment: @user836910: It was mostly like you, just practicing. The next time you make an error like this one you'll know what to look for, and that happens only after having struggled with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function that given an element to search, find the index of that element. Don't write it by yourself, use `std::find` on array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   std::string xx[3];
   xx[0] = "zero";
   xx[1] = "one";
   xx[2] = "two";
   int index = std::find(xx, xx+3, "two") - xx;
   if (index < 3) std::cout << "found in position: " << index << endl;
   else std::cout << "not found" << endl;
}
```

I think in your case it's better to use at least `std::vector` or a `struct` to store your information now in the two arrays

Comment: OP stands for "Original Poster", the person who asked the question / started the thread.